# Showing that the induced map $f_\ast : H_n(X) \to H_n(Y)$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Consider the chain complex $K$ $$\dots \longrightarrow \Bbb Z \overset{\text{id}}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb Z \overset{0}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb Z \overset{\text{id}}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb Z \overset{0}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb Z \overset{\partial_1=p}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb Z \longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow 0 \dots$$ and the chain complex $L$ $$\dots \longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow0 \longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow 0 \overset{\partial_1'}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb Z /p\Bbb Z\longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow 0 \dots$$ The map $\partial_1$ is  multiplying by $p \in \Bbb N$. Let $f : K \to L$ be a chain map, where $$f_0 : \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z, \ m \mapsto [m]_p.$$ Show that the induced map $f_\ast :H_n(K) \to H_n(L)$ is an isomorphism for every $n$. Conclude that a chain map that is not a chain homotopy equivalence may induce isomorphisms on homology.

I've computed the homology groups and found that $H_n(K) = 0$ if $n \ne 0$ and $H_0(K) = \Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$. Similarly $H_n(L) = 0$ for $n \ne 0$ and $H_0(L)=\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$.

Now according to Hatcher the maps $f_\ast : H_n(X) \to H_n(Y)$ are isomorphic if $f : X \to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence. So in this case this would amount to showing that $$f_0 : \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$$ is a homotopy equivalence since for $n \ne 0$ the groups are just trivial and the induced map the trivial maps. This sort of homotopy equivalence between $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$ feels a bit unnatural so I'm thinking whether there is some other result that one can use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you mix up different things. Your exercise deals with the homology of chain complexes and chain homotopy equivalences. When you quote Hatcher, it seems to me that your refer to the section "Homotopy Invariance" on p.110 which deals with the homology of topological spaces and (topological) homotopy equivalences. In the proof of Theorem 2.10 Hatcher comes back to the singular chain complex, but it is not really *explicit*. Only Proposition 2.12 is an explicit result about chain complexes.

In particular you **must not** consider $f_0 : \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$ as a map between topological spaces. It is a map between abelian groups and certainly no homotopy equivalence between topological spaces.

However, it is the $0$-th component of the *unique chain map* $f : K \to L$ with components $f_n : K_n\to L_n$. In fact, since $L_n = 0$ for $n \ne 0$, any chain map $f : K \to L$ must have $f_n = 0$ for $n \ne 0$. Moreover we must have $f_0 \circ \partial_1 = \partial_1' \circ f_1 = 0$ and the only homomorphism with this property is $f_0(m) = [m]_p$. Thus, stretching a point, we could identity $f_0$ with the unique chain map $f : K \to L$. But this chain map is not a chain homotopy equivalence because the only chain map $g : L \to K$ is that having **all** $g_n = 0$ (note that the only homomorphism $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ is the zero homomorphism). But the zero chain map is not a chain homotopy equivalence unless both chain complexes involved are the zero chain complexes.

Nevertheless $f_* : H_0(K) \to H_0(L)$ is an isomorphism. We have
$H_0(K)  = \ker 0/\operatorname{im} \partial_1 = \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and $H_0(L)  = \ker 0/\operatorname{im} \partial'_1 = (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)/0 =  \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. Thus
$$f_*([m]_p) = [f_0(m)]_0 = f_0(m) = [m]_p .$$

Comment: What is this $[f_0(m)]_0$ term here and how come one can conclude that $$[f_0(m)]_0 = [[m]_p]_0 = [m]_p?$$ @PaulFrost

Comment: @Divider $f_* : H_0(K) \to H_0(L)$ is given by $f_*([m]) = [f_0(m)]$. Here $[m]$ denotes the homology class of $m \in \ker 0$, i.e. the equivalence class of $m$ in the quotient $H_0(K) = \ker 0/\operatorname{im} \partial_1 = \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. On the RHS $[f_0(m)]$ denotes the homology class of $f_0(m) \in \ker 0$, i.e. the equivalence class of $f_0(m)$ in the quotient $H_0(L) = \ker 0/\operatorname{im} \partial'_1 = (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)/0$.

Comment: I wrote $[m] = [m]_p$ on the LHS and $[f_0(m)] = [f_0(m)]_0$ on the RHS. The index $0$ indicates that we work in the quotient by the $0$-group, i.e. consider equivalence classes$\mod 0$. In this case $[a]_0 =[b]_0$ iff $a = b$ and so I ommited $[-]_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f \colon C \to D$ be a chain map between two complexes of abelian groups (say).

> If $f$ is an homotopy equivalence$^1$, then $f_* \colon H_n(C) \to H_n(D)$ is an isomorphism for every $n$.

The goal of this exercise is to see that the converse of the above statement is not true.

For that, we consider the chain map $f \colon K \to L$ as you wrote in the question.
Then, as you can check, $f_* \colon H_0(K) \to H_0(L)$ corresponds to the identity $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$; and, for $n \neq 0$, $f_* \colon H_n(K) \to H_n(L)$ is the zero map $0 \to 0$.

Hence, $f_* \colon H_n(K) \to H_n(L)$ is an isomorphism for every $n$, but $f$ is not an homotopy equivalence, since any chain map $L \to K$ is zero (any group homomorphism $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ is zero).

---

$^1$That is, there is a chain map $g \colon D \to C$ such that $gf$ is homotopic to $1_C$, and that $fg$ is homotopic to $1_D$.